# Windows 10 C drive gets slightly bigger everytime I start the computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, disk-space, cpu-usage

I have TightVNC and ScreenConnect on my Windows 10 computer, and every time I turn on my computer and log in, the `C:` partition adds more bytes to the total size of the `C:` partition; it's not a huge amount of byte difference, but enough to notice from the `C:` partition's properties (roughly 1,000 extra bytes or so).

What could cause the increase in used space on the `C:` partition? Could it be updates to the antivirus it has on it? Could it be updates from other software? Could it be from TightVNC taking pictures and storing them?

I am going to look at it some more to determine if there is a much larger increase rather than a few thousand extra bytes added to the total space used on the `C:` partition.

Comment: It's normal, as when a computer is on, the OS is logging information to the system logs, swapping out data from the swap and page file, etc.  @John's answer below also elaborates on additional things.

Comment: Your question is not clear: You start by saying that the partition is getting bigger. But then at about the 1/2 may point, you suddenly switch to saying that it getting more full.

Comment: The Disk Gets bigger in terms of how much space is used up. Total space decreases as computer runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is entirely normal for Windows Vista, Seven, Eight and Ten.  Disk space is used for Temporary Files, Virus signature updates, Windows Updates, other updates and so on.

Regularly run Disk Cleanup (Admin Tools) and include System Files in the cleanup. If the machine is operating normally, it may ask permission to delete Windows.old and you can say OK to this.

In Windows 10 V1909, Start, System, and then Storage. You can set a certain amount of automatic cleanup of old files.